# Encrypted timestamp 448 bit

Tags: date, gwt, encryption, time, timestamp

I try to reverse engineer an GWT-API of a local public transport company (MVG in Munich). They don't offer a public REST-API or something similar. Unfortunately they use some sort of encrypted timestamps which consists of 7 letters. The alphabet is A-Za-z0-9$_ (in this order) which makes 64 different letters. One would need 6 bits to represent these 64 different letters.
So 7 letters * 6 bits/letter makes 42 bits.
I'm pretty sure that it is no bit field.
You can see it yourself on http://www.mvg-live.de/MvgLive/MvgLive.jsp#haltestelle=Am%20M%C3%BCnchner%20Tor&gehweg=0&zeilen=7&ubahn=true&bus=true&tram=true. Look out for (POST) requests to clockservice (http://www.mvg-live.de/MvgLive/mvglive/rpc/clockService, not working without using POST) which gives you the current server time.

Here are a few examples, with the date of the http-response:

```
UeEcvQB: Tue, 29 Jul 2014 23:27:15 GMT
UeGbS0O: Wed, 30 Jul 2014 08:40:13 GMT
UeGbhiJ: Wed, 30 Jul 2014 08:41:13 GMT
UeGozGI: Wed, 30 Jul 2014 09:39:13 GMT
UeGpBv$: Wed, 30 Jul 2014 09:40:13 GMT
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Base64 or some slight variant of Base64. Too little variation to be an encryption (UeG____ for 4 in a row)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to be the number of milliseconds after the Unix epoch (01/01/1970 00:00:00) converted to base-64 using that alphabet.

E.g.: `UeGozGI` can be converted back to decimal using:

```
U = 20
e = 30
G = 6
o = 40
z = 51
G = 6
I = 8

To decimal:

= (((((20 * 64 + 30) * 64 + 6) * 64 + 40) * 64 + 51) * 64 + 6) * 64 + 8
= 1406713147784
= 07/30/2014 09:39:07am
```

Which is (pretty close to) the time you indicates it encodes.

Comment: Perfekt. Thanks a lot. You nailed it.